# Class type doesn't convert to IDisposable and .SaveChanges method doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, entity-framework-6

So i was given an exercise as part of my course and it was to create a ASP.NET MVC application that doesn't have a database or model and generates one using the code. In one section i got given some code you will see below.
I have already tried adding `| IDisposable` to the classes but that still threw the above errors.

As for .SaveChanges not working i have heard this is because Entity framework can't be found but i have tried adding `System.Data.Entity` to the using statements as well as adding a reference in the project options.

This is the problem code:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Models.Product p = new Models.Product();
        p.Product_Code = "SOFT549";
        p.Product_Name = "Book";

        using (var db = new Models.StoreDB()) 
        {
            db.products.Add(p);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Message = "The number of products so far is " + db.products.Count().ToString();
        }

        return View();
    }
  }
```

This is the product class:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Product_Code { get; set; }
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {

    }

}
```

And this is the StoreDB class, which inherits from a blank DbContext which i assume i will be told to add something too later but on the sheet i was given it asks to me to run the code meaning it should definitely compile in this state.

```
    public class StoreDB: DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order_Line> order_lines { get; set; }

    }
```

And just in case you require the order class as well:

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public class Order
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Order_Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime Order_Date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection <Order_Line> Order_Lines { get; set; } 

    public Order()
    {

    }

}
```

And here are the errors in detail again just in case.

> 'StoreDB': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.Double'
>
> 'StoreDB' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges' and no extension method 'SaveChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'StoreDB' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have multiple classes named `StoreDB` located in different namespaces?

Comment: @Igor I don't think i did as this is the only project i have created under this solution and the classes you can see include all the code except for one other class and as you can see they all follow the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the reference to `Entity Framework` using Nuget Package Manager.

When you first run the Solution because `DbContext` doesn't have a parameter it will create a new database in your MsSqlExpress database.

Go through this tutorial for more info: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

---

I think I've spotted two problems, the first is that you dont have a constructor in your StoreDB.

```
public class StoreDB : DbContext
{ 
        public StoreDB() : base() //Add a parameter to Base to specify an existing dB
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<StoreDB>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StoreDB>());

        }

        public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order_Line> order_lines { get; set; }
}
```

The second problem is that `using (var db = new Models.StoreDB())` doesn't implement IDisplosable. You should be doing it like this (only using `using` with the StoreDB not around the Models.StoreDB()):

```
using (var ctx = new StoreDB())
{
    var p = new Product() { Product_Code = "SOFT549",Product_Name = "Book" };
    ctx.Products.Add(p);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I have checked Nuget package manager and it is definitely installed in this project, i was sure i did that anyway but just to certain i double checked.
 
I also followed the tutorial you sent me up to the point i am at now and i can't see anything different about the code except for the fact that i created product p outside of the using statement and the fact that i didn't write it within curly brackets.

Comment: Moving the create of p within the using statement still gives me the same two errors and adding a constructor to StoreDB has given me the following  errors:

`The type cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.`

`The type cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method. There is no implicit reference conversion from to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.`

Comment: Follow the tutorial and then compare the two projects.